# Catching Uncaught exception Exception: SSL read

Tags: php, ssl, exception, unirest

I'm reading a URL that is finicky sometimes and throws a `Uncaught exception Exception: SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 10054` I tried doing this:

```
try {
  $body  = Unirest\Request::get($url);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  print $e;
  return;
}
```

but still, the error is stopping my task. I would like to know if I am missing that will just execute the catch function and not stop it all together.